# Creating Precipitation in AFrame

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I'm creating a game in aframe, and thought it would be really cool to make it start raining. I don't even know where to start, and any way I can think of such as using animations isn't working. So any help I can get would be nice. Thanks! :)

I would like the rain to be in the shape of little rectangular prisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/IdeaSpaceVR/aframe-particle-system-component

```
<a-entity particle-system="preset: rain">

<a-entity particle-system="preset: snow">
```

Comment: Okay, I like this one more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just kidding, I found it, but for anyone who wants to know: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-rain